# read_csv() how to use no delimeter because there's only one column of data

Tags: python, pandas

My data is a collection of tweets, which have quotations, commas, and characters of every type, and they're all separated by newlines. That is the only information in the dataset. Outside of just setting the delimiter to be some character not in the dataset via `pd.read_csv('filename.csv',delimeter=r'someobscurecharacter')`, how do I import this dataset as a dataframe or series using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

My favourite is [yen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_yen):

```
pd.read_csv('filename.csv',delimeter=r'¥')
```

Another idea:

```
pd.read_csv('filename.csv',delimeter=r'☺')
```

Comment: While not what I was looking for, this is basically what I settled for.